# Changing windows title bar color in Xamarin.Forms UWP app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

How to override default blue titlebar color of Xamarin.Forms UWP app through AppShell style or something?
[Color Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqh7y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the `Blue` color of the bar of your sceenshot in shell app,you can set the value of property `Shell.BackgroundColor`:

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            
            <!--change the color here-->
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="#96F3" />

            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks you. I've already set `Shell.BackgroundColor` in my AppShell but it won't work. After your reply i set it to default "Red" and it worked. Then i've set it back to my StaticResource and everything is working fine now.
I think its a Xamarin.Forms bug or something bc before changing to default "Red" color my `Shell.BackgroundColor` did not do anything.